# Iptables outbound block denies inbound

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm trying to block only outbound connections to specific IP addresses, however I want to allow inbound connections from the same IP addresses.

From what I understand about blocking outbound connections, they *shouldn't* block if an inbound connection has been made successfully.

I basically set up rules like this:

```
--append OUTPUT --jump DROP --destination x.x.x.x
```

And to allow established connections:

```
--append INPUT --in-interface eth0 --match state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED --jump ACCEPT
```

I want connections to be allowed when this IP address attempts to connect to the server, but when my server tries to make an outbound connection, it shouldn't be able to make it.

I would like to block complete access for the server to make outbound connections to `x.x.x.x`. However when a user from that IP wishes to access the server they should be able to visit sites on certain ports.

Comment: You also need to check ESTABLISHED, otherwise how is TCP going to complete handshakes? :-)

Comment: I have `--append INPUT --in-interface eth0 --match state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED --jump ACCEPT` do I need this outbound?

Comment: I would recommend nftables: it is the new iptables, ip6tables, arptables, ...

Comment: The question is not clear. I think what you want is simple, but it is hard to tell what you want. Edit the question to make it clear. Tell us what you are trying to achieve. Tell us what you have tried. Tell us what went wrong.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have to edited the post, but I would like to block complete access for the server to make outbound connections to `x.x.x.x`. However when a user from that IP wishes to access the server they should be able to visit sites on certain ports. When I have attempted this I just cannot connect.

Comment: Is your firewall stopping you from editing the question? (you suggest this in your last comment)

Comment: @johnramsden Check out my updated answer, you will love it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there with your attempted firewall rules. Here's what you need to allow inbound traffic from host `10.10.10.10` while stopping outbound traffic to that address:

1. Allow inbound (presumably to any port)
2. Allow outbound replies to established inbound connections
3. Block remaining outbound traffic

So,

```
iptables -A INPUT --src 10.10.10.10 --jump ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT --match state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED --jump ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --dst 10.10.10.10 --jump DROP
```

You don't really need the `INPUT` rule unless you have later rules reaching `DENY`/`REJECT` or your policy is set that way.

Comment: With this block outbound traffic though? Or would the fact that related or established connections are allowed mean once a single user has connected from the source IP, all outbound connections will be allowed?

Comment: Thanks. Worked great.

Comment: So, output has states, too? Hah, good to know. Im gonna test it, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting it wrong! Here is what i understand:

First of all, look at your `input` rule. It shall allow input by `state`, but what does `state` mean? It means, that traffic has gone `out` from your server to this address, before! So this rule will never match, if you block `output` (for this address) completely.

This is why your complete endeavor is not possible, `state` is only available in `input`.

There might be some hacky solution. But with the given options it is not possible.

PS

After your question i checked for an old topic again and guess what. After reading your post again, it stroke me, that this is EXACTLY what you want. Look at [PortKnocking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Port_knocking).

It adds a component to your request, which makes it even better; randomness.

Just configure a knocking scheme and not only allow `output` connections, but also `input` only if the correct `knocking` has happened, then.

Comment: So my only option would be whitelisting certain input ports for output? Is that possible? I'm thinking allow request on INPUT to x.x.x.x:8080 go OUTPUT. ie: `--append OUTPUT --jump ALLOW --destination x.x.x.x ... `

Comment: I didn't check the syntax, but this is correct. Just as i told, your requirement can't be met. If there is some possibility to run a script on incoming packets, you could change the rules. But last time i've been working on firewall rules, this wasn't possible.

Comment: This is correct. Based on your example you intend to allow incoming connections from some IP. However, they can't be RELATD/ESTABLISHED as you've prohibited starting connections from this server. Therefore, your state should be set to 'NEW'.

Comment: But this wouldnt block anything, would it. There was a misunderstanding, how it works.